# inicializing a structure with arrays of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

So i have this structure jogo and i want to create a variable of that type and inicialize it and modify it.

```
typedef struct jogo 
{
   int ident;/*idp of a product*/
   char *nome; /* string that describes a team eg. Barcelona */
   char **equipas; /*array of strings e.g. ["Barcelona","Madrid"]*/
   int *score; /*array of ints e.g. [1,2]*/
}* jogo;

jogo *sistema_jog;
```

To do that i created an init funcion the problem is that when i call it on the main i get segmentation fault core dumped error and i dont understand why.

```
void init(jogo s)
{
    s = (struct jogo*) calloc(MAX_SIZE,sizeof(struct jogo));
    s->equipas = (char**) calloc(2,sizeof(char));
}
```

Really any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @MikeCAT unfortunately that doesnt resolve my question, so what should i do???

Comment: Change the argument `s`'s type to a pointer to `jogo`, modify the function body `init` to meet with the change, and modify the caller of `init` to pass a pointer to the variable to modify.

Comment: i did part of that but in the body i  get this `error expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type`

Comment: What you want to do may be `(*s)->equipas`

Comment: could u type what u mean pls because im not understanding.

Comment: Typical what want `pointer-to-struct-or-union type` is the arrow operator `->`, so I guessed that you are struggling to modify the `s->equipas = (char**) calloc(2,sizeof(char));` part.

Comment: no the problem is that im struggling to inicialize the variable *sistema_jog

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Note that `sistema_jog` is a pointer to a pointer to `struct jogo`.

Comment: Ok i rewrite another question